# How to get peak memory usage of python script?

Tags: python, memory, out-of-memory, scientific-computing

I'm doing some extensive scientific python calculations and whant to know execution time and memory footprint of python script.

So how to get **peak** memory usage of python script?

If it matters I'm on Windows and use python 2.7.

Answer (score 5):

The [resource](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html) module can give you this. Works in both Python 2 and Python 3.

```
import resource
resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
```

This is peak memory in **kilobytes**. The user and system time is also included in the value from getrusage.

Comment: This is only available in Unix - in the Python Standard Library documentation, it's listed under "Unix Specific Services": https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/index.html

Answer (score 4):

For the peak memory, as you are on Windows, you can use `psutil` and [psutil.Process.memory_info](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.memory_info), for example to get the peak working set size, in bytes:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> p = psutil.Process()
>>> p.memory_info().peak_wset
238530560L
```

As per the link above,  you can get more details about some Windows specific fields on this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684874(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: And what about Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for a memory profiler.
Memory_profiler is one that you can dive into which line is giving you the problems and with some querying you can figure out which area is the biggest in memory consumption.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler
and since you are using windows it will also need this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil

Good Luck!

Comment: I don't think this is what the question asked, the question was about to get the peak memory.